# What is "base" doing in this property?

Tags: c#, .net

I stumbled upon this in the project I will be working on:

```
public int? OrgId
{
    get { return base["OrgId"] as int?; }
    set { base["OrgId"] = value; }
}
```

Clicking on OrgId, Resharper takes me to method of this signature :

```
public override object this[string propertyName] { get; set; }
```

What does base[""] do ? And what means the this[] part of the override ? Couldn't find anything meaningful on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the base class has an indexer and that indexer accepts a string as a possible parameter. What that indexer does, I don't know, that's in the base class.\

In the `get` you're actually pulling from that indexer, and in the `set` you're hitting the `set` of that indexer. It appears it's just a wrapper so that the consumers of this class don't have to use the indexer **or** it's an implementation where they don't have to have internal class properties.

I hope it's not the latter, because if it is they could have written a lot less code with something like:

```
public int? OrgId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

`this[]` is an indexer: [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

`base[]` runs indexer defined in `base` class. It can be used when indexer is overridden in child class and you'd like to use the one defined in `base` class.